# why the inconsistency with org mode code line labels and links

Tags: org-mode, org-link

In org mode and in a source code special block, I can add code line labels, which have `ref:` in the label -- but when I make a link there, I have to omit the `ref:`. For example:

```
#+begin_src csharp
1044 string foo = someFunction(1234);
1045 if (foo == "1")
1046 {
1047     bar = 5; //  (ref:my-code-line-label)
1048 }
// etc etc
#+end_src

There's a bug [[(my-code-line-label)][right here]].
```

This seems inconsistent. Why do I have to omit the `ref:` bit? This always confuses me; it seems like it would be simpler to just make the label and the links to that line of code be exactly the same. I don't see any particular reference to this in [the org manual](https://orgmode.org/manual/Internal-Links.html). Any insights?

Comment: No particular insights as to `why`, but the `how` is clear: `org-link-search` takes the undecorated label from the link (i.e. without the `ref:`) as argument and decorates it internally. By default, it adds the `ref:` part, and creates a regexp for it (including the parens as part of the match) and that's what it searches for. If you pass `ref:foo`, then it looks for `(ref:ref:foo)` and that fails. There is some provision to change that default using a `:label-fmt` property, but I don't know how to trigger that. You might find something through git archaelogy or by posting a question on the ML

Comment: Thanks for the investigation! Here's my idea (which I should send to the org-mode list): get rid of the special behavior for code line labels and just make this work with dedicated targets: in regular parts of my org file, I use <<link-target>> and can make links to that. It would be simple and consistent to make that also work the same when <<link-target>> is inside a code block.

Answer (score 0):

See [this thread](https://list.orgmode.org/877crcxdb0.fsf@localhost/T/#t) on the org-mode mailing list for some background. There, Ihor Radchenko pointed me to `org-coderef-label-format`:

> the way coderefs appear in the code are completely configurable using
> org-coderef-label-format ("(ref:%s)" by default) and using -l src code
> switch.

And if I customize that to just `(%s)`, I get the kind of consistent behavior that I'm looking for.